# TextBlock with Text different for each run

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

How it is possible to bind different text for each run command?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Sententce1" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="36" />
    <LineBreak/><Run Text="Sententce2" Foreground="Red" FontSize="22"  FontStyle="Italic"/>
    <LineBreak/><Run Text="Sententce3" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="36"/>
    <LineBreak/><Run Text="Sententce4" Foreground="Green" FontSize="36" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: By "command" you mean element? With bindings. Bind them to different properties of the view model, template, user control, or whatever. What are you asking?

Comment: Each sentence is a word translated from one language to another. user types in a word(s) into a TextBox, and a function converts each word(s) and displays translation in the TextBlock. via Run commands.

Comment: Have you tried `<Run Text="{Binding SentanceN}" />`? Assuming you have a view-model setup as the `DataContext`.

Comment: @LetzerWille Are you saying there will be an arbitrary number of words in a collection?

Comment: @EdPlunkett the number of words fixed: just five.

Comment: @Laith  I am new to wpf and have not used view-model yet. I am trying to use mm8 suggestion and create dependency  property. So far no success but I am learning.....

Comment: You don't need to create any dependency property...you just set the DataContext of the window (or the TextBlock) to an instance of a class with the "Sentence1", ... properties and set the values of these properties.

Comment: @mm8 It is amazing how much could be done with with binding and DataContext in WPF, if one knows how .... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in the .NET Framework 4, you can bind the `Text` property of a `Run` element just like you can bind the `Text` property of a `TextBlock`.

This means that you could define three different source properties and bind to these as usual:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Sententce1" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="36" />
    <LineBreak/><Run Text="{Binding Sentence1}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="22"  FontStyle="Italic"/>
    <LineBreak/><Run Text="{Binding Sentence2}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="36"/>
    <LineBreak/><Run Text="{Binding Sentence3}" Foreground="Green" FontSize="36" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
</TextBlock>
```